# [In mobile]: The page content dose not overflow over the PageContainer

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, pro-components, pro-layout

At present, we are utilizing ProLayout from antd-pro. I have enclosed the content with a PageContainer wrapper, which functions well on larger screens. However, on mobile screens, it does not work as intended, as the content overflows the PageContainer.

[image]

It is unnecessary for the page content to overflow the PageContainer because the PageContainer wrapper should automatically adjust its size, the parent div needs to control the size of the child div...

```js
export const ReactTable = (props: IReactTableInterface) => {
    const { columns, data, pageOptions, showPagination, pageNumber, pages, pageSizeCount, setPageSizeCount,
        setPageNumber, noDataText } = props;
    const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(1);
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        prepareRow,
        page,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            initialState: {
                pageIndex: pageNumber || 0,
                pageSize: pageSizeCount || 10,
                pageCount: pages
            },
        },
        usePagination
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        setPageNum(pageNumber + 1);
    }, [pageNumber]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (setPageNumber && pageIndex > -1) {
            setPageNumber(pageIndex);
        }
    }, [pageIndex]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (setPageSizeCount) {
            setPageSizeCount(pageSize);
        }
    }, [pageSize]);

    // Render the UI for your table
    return (
        <>
            <table {...getTableProps()} className={css(StyleSheet.table)}>
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {page.length ? (
                        page.map((row, i) => {
                            prepareRow(row)
                            return (
                                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                        return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                                    })}
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    ) : (
                        <tr className={css(StyleSheet.noData)}>
                            <div className={'no-data-text'}>
                                {noDataText || 'No Data'}
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {(showPagination && page.length) ? (
                <div className={css(StyleSheet.pagination)}>
                    <div className={css(StyleSheet.btn)}>
                        <Button
                            size={'large'}
                            onClick={() => previousPage()}
                            disabled={!canPreviousPage}
                        >Previous</Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className={css(StyleSheet.pageChange)}>
                        <div>
                            <span>{`Page `}</span>
                            <Input
                                size={'large'}
                                type={'number'}
                                className={css(StyleSheet.input)}
                                value={pageNum}
                                min={1}
                                max={pageCount}
                                onChange={e => {
                                    const page = e.target.value && Number(e.target.value)
                                    setPageNum(page);
                                }}
                                onBlur={e => gotoPage(pageNum - 1)}
                            />
                            <span>{` of ${pageCount}`}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Select
                                size={'large'}
                                value={pageSize}
                                onChange={value => setPageSize(value)}
                                options={(pageOptions || [10, 15, 20, 25]).map((value) => ({ value, label: `${value} rows` }))}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={css(StyleSheet.btn, StyleSheet.next)}>
                        <Button
                            size={'large'}
                            onClick={() => nextPage()}
                            disabled={!canNextPage}
                        >Next</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </>
    );
}

const StyleSheet: any = {
    table: {
        width: '100%',
        border: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important',
        '> thead': {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(245, 245, 245)',
            boxShadow: '0 2px 15px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 15%)',
            '> tr': {
                '> th': {
                    padding: '5px 10px',
                    borderRight: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
                    textAlign: 'left'
                },
            }
        },
        '> tbody': {
            '> tr': {
                borderBottom: 'solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
                '> td': {
                    borderRight: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.02)',
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                    padding: '10px 7px',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                }
            },
        }
    },
    pagination: {
        border: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
        display: 'flex',
        padding: '5px'
    },
    next: {
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: '0px',
    },
    pageChange: {
        margin: 'auto',
        display: 'flex',
        gap: '100px'
    },
    btn: {
        '& .ant-btn': {
            width: '200px',
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',   
            background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            borderColor: 'transparent !important',
            ':hover': {
                background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
                color: '#fff'
            },
        },
        '& .ant-btn[disabled]': {
            width: '200px',
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
            background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            borderColor: 'transparent !important',
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    input: {
        width: '60px'
    },
    noData: {
        height: '100px',
        '& .no-data-text': {
            color: '#00000080',
            margin: '40px 0',
            width: '100%',
            textAlign: 'center',
            position: 'absolute',
        }
    }
}
```